# Do I need to resize the image to 2^a x 2^b before performing a fast fourier transform?

Tags: image-processing

Do I need to resize the image to 2^a x 2^b before performing a fast fourier transform?

Comment: Read this book: http://programmingcomputervision.com/. It has the answers to those types of questions

Comment: @Kristian: I did searches for FFT and Fourier, and couldn't find a single match in the entire book.

Comment: i must have linked to the wrong thing then -- the book i'm thinking of, which i've read, did have that stuff. thanks

Comment: There are many different algorithms for FFT, some have the restriction of working with powers of 2 and some don't. Wikipedia has a bunch of them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fft

Answer (score 0):

For the cases where you do need to use a power of 2, rather than resizing, you should pad with zeros.

In some cases, even if the algorithm you are using is not limited to powers of 2, it may be more efficient to pad to that size anyway (particularly if your image is just slightly smaller than the next power of 2).  Also, if your image is not square, you can pad to a square image of 2^a before taking the fft.  Some algorithms will do this behind the scenes anyway - pad your image to square, take the fft, then crop back to the original size.

Zero padding is also sometimes used to increase the number of points in the output - a higher frequency "resolution", although since you're not adding any more data it's more like an interpolation.

Whether you **need** to do this will depend on what fft library you are using.